# How to install fieldtest?

Tags: android

I am trying to find a way of installing `FieldTest.apk` on my HTC Wildfire S. Trying to install right away yields:

```
[evad@v3350 Downloads]$ adb install FieldTest.apk
961 KB/s (127564 bytes in 0.129s)
pkg: /data/local/tmp/FieldTest.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE]
```

So I did a bit of googling and discovered apktool which I've used to decode apk and remove `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.phone"` bit from `AndroidManifest.xml`, but then I've got:

```
[evad@v3350 Downloads]$ adb install FieldTest.apk
1247 KB/s (77631 bytes in 0.060s)
pkg: /data/local/tmp/FieldTest.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you build your app with JDK7?
I met simmilar situation with JDK7.
When I have switched it to JDK6, it was resolved.